# How to delegate focus event?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Focus and blur jQuery events not bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577971/focus-and-blur-jquery-events-not-bubbling)

```
var default_input_value = null;
jQuery('body').on('focus focusout', 'input[type="text"]', function(event){
    if(event.type === 'focus'){
        default_input_value = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery(this).val('');
    }else if(event.type === 'focusout')
        if(jQuery(this).val().length === 0)
        jQuery(this).val(default_input_value);
    }
);
```

This code simply does not respond to the event.
P.S.
it is important that there would be `input[type="text"]`, because `jQuery focus` also fires on `checkbox` in some situations....

Comment: Try on `focusin` see if that works, or maybe `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: `default_input_value` seems to hold the value for the last focued input and not one for each. Are you trying to solve some watermark/placeholder issues?

Comment: @elclanrs thanks man, `focus` returns `focusin`

Comment: @Stefan, no, problem was in `event.type === 'focus'`

Comment: the focus event doesn't bubble. google, man. who the hell upvoted this?

Comment: @AndyRay please tell it to browser creators.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Under [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) jquery document, there is a description:

The `focus` and `blur` events are specified by the W3C to not bubble, but jQuery defines cross-browser `focusin` and `focusout` events that do bubble. When `focus` and `blur` are used to attach delegated event handlers, jQuery maps the names and delivers them as `focusin` and `focusout` respectively. For consistency and clarity, use the bubbling event type names.

Hope this would be useful.

And you can try this code:

```
var default_input_value = null;
jQuery('body').on('focusin focusout', 'input[type="text"]', function(event){
    if(event.type === 'focusin'){
        default_input_value = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery(this).val('');
    }else if(event.type === 'focusout'){
        if(jQuery(this).val().length === 0)
        jQuery(this).val(default_input_value);
    }
});
```