# How to add classes input focused on checkout and product review forms?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, magento2

If an input is in focus or has a value, I want to add a class to all inputs parent .field div. For example on the product page review form or on the checkout page shipping form. If the input is in focus I would add an "active" class and if the input has a value I would add the class "hasavalue."

When I try to use jquery, nothing happens on the product page review form inputs or on the checkout page inputs.

Here's the jquery I am using:

```
requirejs(['jquery'],function($){

   $(document).ready(function(){


    $('.field input').focus(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
    }).blur(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');
    });



    $('.field input').blur(function(){

        if ( $(this).val() ) {
              $(this).parent().parent().addClass('hasavalue');
        } else{
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('hasavalue');
        }

     });

  });
});
```

Do I need to use knockout? If so, how can I translate this simple jquery to work with all inputs in Magento?

Comment: The checkout hits the .ready() point before the fields load in because knockout loads them in using ajax. You have to either work this out through knockout and Magento's checkout 'system' or if you're only doing something basic for styling, you may find it easier to use a JS mutation observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fields are not loaded yet, you need to delegate the event handlers. However, 'focus' and 'blur' do not bubble, so you need to use jQuery's `.on('focusin')` and `.on('focusout')`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14496244/6127393

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').on('focusin', '.field input', function() {

    $(this).closest('.field').addClass('active');

  }).on('focusout', '.field input', function() {

    let fieldDiv = $(this).closest('.field');
    fieldDiv.removeClass('active');
    // toggleClass eliminates need for if else, just put the test as second parameter, true adds class while false removes it
    fieldDiv.toggleClass('hasavalue', ($(this).val() !== ''));

  })


  // adding a field afterwards just for demonstration to show it still works
  $('<div class="field"><label>loaded after document ready</label><br><input></div>').appendTo('body')

});
```

```css
/* just example for visual verification */

.field {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: orange;
}

.field.active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.field.hasavalue {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- structure does not matter as long as there is an input inside .field -->
<div class="field">
  <input>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```