# onblur doesn't work when i clone input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change input type text to password. But it doesn't work in ie8. I found a solution; clone and replace input but onblur doesn't work after clone.

The debugger doesn't break OnBlur function. Can somebody show me?

Here is js code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("Password");
    var input2 = input.cloneNode(false);
    input2.id = 'password1';
    input2.type = 'password';
    $('#Password').focus(function () {
       input.parentNode.replaceChild(input2, input);
       input2.focus();
    });
    $('#password1').blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == Passwordtxt) {
            document.getElementById("password1").setAttribute("type", "text");
            $(this).val(Passwordtxt);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$('#password1').blur(function () {
```

to

```
$('body').on('focusout','#password1',function () {
```

See [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

The `focus` and `blur` events are specified by the W3C to not bubble, but jQuery defines cross-browser `focusin` and `focusout` events that do bubble. When `focus` and `blur` are used to attach delegated event handlers, jQuery maps the names and delivers them as `focusin` and `focusout` respectively. For consistency and clarity, use the bubbling event type names.

Answer (score -2):

use `on` event delegate

try this

```
$(document).on('blur','#password1',function () {...
```

replacing the `document` with the closest element is preffered

Comment: No,this can't work. `blur` will not bubble. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577971/focus-and-blur-jquery-events-not-bubbling