# AngularJs: document.body.onfocus inside directive controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to capture the event when the user close or cancel the `File Upload` Window

`<input type="file">`

Since there's no built in listener for the close event of the file upload, I am trying to capture it via the `document.body.focus` event, something like the one [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628544/how-to-detect-when-cancel-is-clicked-on-file-input)

I'm getting it to run using javascript

```
document.body.onfocus = function() { console.log("hit me") }
```

Now I need to implement it in Angular in my directive so that I could put logic inside the `focus` event using the objects in the controller.

How to access the `onfocus` event of `document.body` inside an angular controller?

From @Phil suggestion (using link)

```
 ... this is a directive with controller
angular.directive("addPost", addPost);

addPost.$inject = ["$document", "$log"];

function addPost($document, $log) {

    return {
        ...
        link: link,
        ...
    };

    function link() {
        $document.find('body').on('focus', function (e) {
            $log.debug('HIT ME!');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Try to use `ng-focus`.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. in my application the `<body>` element is outside the angular scope, i mean it is on an MVC view. How can I attach ng-focus on it?

Comment: You could try `$document.find('body').on('focus', function(e) { ... })`

Comment: @Phil I already injected the `$document` but im getting `$document.find is not a function`?

Comment: @LincAbela that's odd, it's certainly there in my app. Can you show your code? You could also try `angular.element($document[0].body).on(...`

Comment: please show some code ..

Comment: Why don't you try `angular.element(document.querySelector("body"))`

Comment: Do you really need a controller there? I'd just use the `link` function and inject `$document` at the directive level. That's where you're meant to do DOM manipulation anyway

Comment: @Phil also no luck using `angular.element` im getting `Cannot read property 'body' of undefined`

Comment: @Vineet because that's not testable

Comment: @Phil no, the controller not meant to manipulat dom - this is just special case, im just trying to get the element focus event. most of the code in the controller is not DOM manipulation

Comment: @Phil, Will you please elaborate it for me ? Please.

Comment: @LincAbela I'd still do that part in the `link`

Comment: @Vineet ive tried `angular.element(document.querySelector("body")).on('focus', function (e) { console.log("HIT ME"); });` no error but the focus event doesnt get hit

Comment: Start from the beginning, what does: document.find('body') return? My guess is nothing b/c the controller is instantiated before the directive is attached to the DOM. Use the link function for this as suggested above.

Comment: @Vineet global variables are difficult to mock and inject so it makes testing difficult. That's why Angular provides the [`$window`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service for example

Comment: Can I use `link` even with a controller? I just dont want to refactor much on this. Since I was just needed a simple stuff on the onfocus event. if you know what I mean

Comment: @LincAbela yes, of course. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Thanks for your words @Phil

Comment: if I use `link: function($scope, element, attr)` - how to call the `document.body.onfocus`? is the suggestions above still relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `link` / `postLink` function to perform DOM operations. For example

```
.directive('addPost', ['$document', '$log', function($document, $log) {
    return {
        // snip
        require: 'addPost',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attr, addPostCtrl) {
            // scope is shared with the controller
            // you can also access properties on the controller itself
            // via addPostCtrl
            $document.find('body').on('focusin', function(e) {
                $log.debug('HIT ME!');
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Tried it. Somehow - The focus event doesn't get hit.

Comment: @LincAbela do any *focus* events actually happen?

Comment: this is my use case, i have a `File Upload`, and I expect when I close the `file upload window`, it should hit the `document.body.focus` - I tested it via javascript and it does hit the focus event. just trying to implement it in angular. does that make sense?

Comment: @LincAbela I don't think "focus" events propagate up to the body. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577971/focus-and-blur-jquery-events-not-bubbling

Comment: hmmmm. But I tried in javascript a`<script> document.body.onfocus = function() { console.log("Hit ME"); }` and it is hitting the focus event when I close the File Upload Window though.

Comment: Im using <input type="file"> by the way.

Comment: @LincAbela This is starting to sound like an [*XY problem*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps you should go back to the start and describe what you're trying to do instead of how you think you should do it

Comment: I also mention there why I want it to access in the controller. because i am going to use the object inside the controller on the focus event.

Comment: @LincAbela I've added some extra info about communicating with the controller

Comment: I see! now we just need to hit the `focus` event which is still im not succesfull

Comment: @LincAbela did you try `focusin`?

Comment: no luck using `on("focus")` neither `on("focusin")` though :(

Comment: yeah ive tried exactly what you suggest. but the focus event never gets hit when I open and close/cancel the fileupload - I am also expecting to hit it when I refresh the page. but the focus event never gets fired.